# Lock a mutex around an exit in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

This code can print "Exiting" multiple times, as you might expect:

```
def print_and_exit
  puts "Exiting"
  exit
end

Array.new(100) { Thread.new { sleep 1; print_and_exit } }.each(&:join)
```

But the behavior is the same even when you protect it with a mutex:

```
def print_and_exit
  puts "Exiting"
  exit
end

mutex = Mutex.new

Array.new(100) { Thread.new { sleep 1; mutex.lock; print_and_exit } }.each(&:join)
```

So it seems that *after* `exit` is called (and the mutex cleaned up), but *before* the process is actually exited, other threads continue to run. How can this be prevented?

#### Note

- This isn't due to `exit`'s receiver. The same behavior occurs with `Thread.main.exit`
- Doesn't make a difference if you use `mutex.synchronize`
- This is with MRI 2.5.0p0

Comment: Actually I *wouldn't* expect that to print multiple times. [`exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) should tank the process.

Comment: @tadman multiple threads can hit the `puts` before one of them hits `exit`. It depends on how they're scheduled, but I usually get 2 or 3.

Comment: Is that with Jruby or MRI or some other Ruby?

Comment: Good point, MRI.

Comment: Are you looking to prevent `exit` from being called more than once, or for `exit` to force-kill all other threads before exiting?

Comment: I guess the former? I expect that if you lock a mutex and never unlock it, the code inside should only run once.

Comment: `lock` can fail and raise, so you may need to watch out for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168143/discussion-between-max-and-tadman).